# Compute $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_0^{\infty}f_n(x)dx$ for $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\sin(\frac{x}{n})$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Define $f_n:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $f_n(x)=\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\sin(\frac{x}{n})$. Compute $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\int\limits_0^{\infty}f_n(x)dx$.

I'm trying to use the dominated convergence theorem.

So to find a dominated function,
$|f_n(x)|=\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}|\sin(\frac{x}{n})|\leq\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\frac{x}{n}=\frac{1}{n\sqrt{x}}\leq\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$

But this function cannot be used because it is not integrable on $(0,\infty)$.
I  really appreciate your help in solving this question.

Comment: $|\sin(x)| \le \min\{|x|,1\}$.

Comment: don't we have $|\sin(a)|\leq|a|$ for any $a$?

Comment: Yes, and we also have $|\sin(a)| \le 1$ for any $a$.

Comment: ah..  So you are saying to take $\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}$? on $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Not quite.  You need your argument as well.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Well.. so are you suggesting  to divide the $(0,\infty)$ to two portions, $(0,1)$ and $[1,\infty)$ and use the two functions appropriately ?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am suggesting.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith thank you. And just to make it more clear.. then we will be applying the dominated convergence theorem in to two parts separately right ?

Comment: You can dominate it by the single function $\min\{x^{-1/2}, x^{-3/2}\}$.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: Or, having established it is in $L^1$, we can now do it like the answer from @Oily Milshtein says.

Comment: @PacoAdajar It is an upper bound.  So it is correct as stated.

Comment: You're right, I just woke up and am not lucid yet. What was I thinking, haha. Oops!

Answer (score 1):

I would try to make a substitution for the integral.

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^{3/2}}\sin(x/n)dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\sin(x)}{x^{3/2}}dx$$.

The quantity in the right integral converges since $|\sin(x)| < 1$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}$. Thus, the limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ is 0.

Comment: Can you please explain why the integral on the right should be finite...

Comment: You haven't really explained why the right integral converges.

Comment: @Stephen Montgomery-Smith the reason for that is as follows: if $f \le g \le h$ on $I$ and both $\int_I \! f$ and $\int_I \! h$ converge, so does $\int_I \! g$. (The inequalities as given aren't strict, but that hardly matters.)

Comment: Yes, but $1/x^{3/2}$ doesn't converge on $[0,\infty)$.

Comment: Right. In that case you break it into $[0, 1]$ and $[1, +\infty)$. Around $0$, $\sin{x} \sim x$ so the integral on $[0, 1]$ might as well be $\int_0^1 \! x^{-1/2} \, dx$, which we know to converge.